# Get parent component dom element in child component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Here is how my parent component looks like .

**In HTML**

```
    <a href="#" (click)="saveDetails()" #saveDetails>
    <app-tab-product *ngFor="let cat of category"></app-tab-product>//parent component
```

**In Typescript**

```
//In parent component.    
 saveDetails(){
   if(this.saveDetails.nativeElement.hasAttribute("data-action")== "next"){
      //save from child requested on next click.
    }

}
```

And inside child component `typescript`  i am using

`@ViewChild('saveDetails') saveDetails:ElementRef;//child component (tab-product)`
 But it shows undefined inside child component.

```
  this.saveDetails.nativeElement.setAttribute("data-action","next");
  this.saveDetails.nativeElement.click();
```

There is next button inside child component . If user click on next button inside child component i want to click save button of parent component so that data of child component will be saved. Method `saveDetails()` is in parent component typescript file.

Comment: What are you going to do with this element? Wouldn't be better if your child component exposed some `@Output`?

Comment: Can you also add `saveDetails` method?

Comment: @yurzui thankou for ur time see the edit

Comment: I can suggest you an option you can go with `<app-tab-product *ngFor="..." (someEvent)="saveDetails()"`. So instead of having `@ViewChild` in child component emit output event from it